# Update data when value changes Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, electron

I have quite a complicated situation and i'm not amazing at Vue so I need some help.
I have a Firebase DB that gets an array (clients) and displays it.

```
const clientsRef = db.ref('clients')
firebase: {
    clients: {
        source: clientsRef,
        //data has been retrieved from firebase
        readyCallback: function() {
            this.getSiteCount() // Get number of sites associated with client
            this.loaded = true // Hide loader bar once this becomes true
        }
    }
},
```

On load complete `getSiteCount()` will get the clients unique ID and compare it against the `sites` DB and count how many exist. Below code simply loops around each `client` and then checks how many `sites` have the `client_id` of `aClient['.key']`. Not really important this works and gets the count and adds it to the clients array.

```
getSiteCount: function() {
        this.clients.forEach((server, clientIndex) => {
            this.clients[clientIndex].siteCount= 0
           serverContactsRef.orderByChild('client_id').equalTo(server['.key']).on('child_added', (clientDetails) => {
                this.clients[clientIndex].siteCount= this.clients[clientIndex].siteCount+ 1

            })
        })
    },
```

Now in my html I have `v-for="clients in filterClients"` and the computed function...

```
filterClients: function() {
    function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.siteCount < b.siteCount) {
            return 1
        }
        if (a.siteCount > b.siteCount) {
            return -1
        }
        return 0
    }
    return this.clients.sort(compare)
}
```

I suspect because the `getSiteCount()` function runs once the clients have been pulled (0.5s delay) from the DB it's initial `siteCount` value is 0 and `filterClients` runs before those values get set. I need to delay `filterClients()` until the `getSiteCount()` function runs or need it to update automatically when the `getSiteCount()` function runs.

Can someone help me make sure the initial load of the page displays the clients in order of how many sites it has (`siteCount`)

Comment: maybe it's due to some reactivity caveats https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Answer (score 0):

It was in fact a Caveat.

Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue

I changed 
`this.clients[clientIndex].siteCount= 0`
to
`Vue.set(this.clients[clientIndex], 'contractsNr', 0)`

Updates when the data comes in perfectly now.

Thanks Jacob